# Bash Grep exact search

Tags: bash, search, grep

I am trying to find an exact word in a file. The word is myServer and the file contents in which I am trying to find it are:

```
This is myServer and it is cool
This is myServer-test and it is cool
```

Here're the results of my various attempts to do this:

```
grep '^myServer$' test-file.txt
grep -Fx myServer test-file.txt

--> no results

grep -w myServer test-file.txt
grep -w myServer test-file.txt
grep '\<myServer\>' test-file.txt
grep '\bmyServer\b' test-file.txt
-->
This is myServer and it is cool
This is myServer-test and it is cool
```

Am I missing some switch here?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try grep with word boundaries:

```
 grep '\<myServer\>' test-file.txt
```

**EDIT:** Looks like you don't want to treat hyphen as word boundary. Use grep like this for that purpose:

```
grep -E '\<myServer\>([^-]|$)'  test-file.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, but this still returns both lines

Comment: Yes it will because hyphen is also considered a word boundary.

Comment: Yes, it now works after I treat hyphen as word boundary. Is there a generic regx I can use because there are multiple other files in which I need to perform an exact search in & they may have different word-boundaries in use...?

Comment: In that case you will need to figure out and let me know all those word boundary characters.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow assign this regex search string to a variable and perform an operation on it? For example, newvar=`grep -E '\<myServer\>([^-]|$)'  test-file.txt` | cut -d ' ' -f 3 ..?

Comment: Yes sure you can do `newvar=$(grep -oE '\<myServer\>([^-]|$)' test-file.txt)`

Comment: One last question on this: I am actually trying to use myvar1='myServer' and after this, I am trying to do myvar2=$(grep -oE '\<${myvar1}\>([^-]|$)' test-file.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3). This is not giving out result and myvar2 is null. What should I correct here..?

Comment: Use double quotes in shell if you are using variables. So use: `myvar2=$(grep -oE "\<${myvar1}\>([^-]|$)" test-file.txt`. You probably don't need to use cut since I am using `grep -o`

Comment: That didn't work. So I tweaked it a bit. 1--> var1=("\<myServer\>([^-]|$") 2--> var2=$(grep -oE "${var1}" test-file.txt) 3--Results--> var2 is null / has no value after script run..

Comment: You're changing your problem gradually within this comments :) You first wrote `myvar1='myServer'` and you're trying to store whole regex in var1.

Comment: If you want to store regex in variable then use: `var1='\<myServer\>([^-]|$)'` and then `var2=$(grep -oE "${var1}" test-file.txt)` will work.

Comment: @Sunshine, if you use double quotes, then you should take care of special characters. In your case, you need to write `"\\<myServer\\>..."`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\<` and `\>` to identify beginning and end of words. So for example given `\<myS` to grep would search for lines with a word starting with `myS`.

Naturally, to search for an exact word, you would search like this:

```
grep '\<myServer\>' test-file.txt
```

---

In most of your attempts, you are doing completely irrelevant stuff:

- `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the *line*.
- `-F` searches for multiple fixed strings
- `-x` searches for whole lines matching the regex

Note: your `-w` would work correctly. However, it seems that your definition of "whole word" is different from what POSIX thinks.

Comment: Doesn't work: grep '\<myServer\>' test-file.txt 
This is myServer and it is cool
This is myServer-test and it is cool

Comment: @Sunshine, maybe you should define your expectation of "whole word"? To me (and apparently to the POSIX standard) `myServer` in `myServer-test` is a whole word. Do you want it to be separated by whitespace?

Comment: I only wanted to be able to search for an exact word in a file. Sorry if I was not clear. Apparently, Anubhav has suggested an answer above already. Thanks

Comment: @Sunshine, like he says there, you need to be more precise on what you consider word boundary. For example, does `!` or `.` count as word boundary? Are you thinking of only whitespace as word boundary or some of the punctuation are included? If the later, which punctuations are include and which not?

Comment: Yes, I understand. The issue is I am going to search through a dump of log files, so I am not really aware of any specifics about word boundaries which might be present...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\b` which means a word boundary:

```
rep '\bmyServer\b' test-file.txt
```

Comment: Sorry this still results both lines